# Is there a platform to collect sites with good UI design?

Tags: user-interface

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Like Behance or Dribbble, but not necessarily for your own work. Or Pinterest but specifically for pinning website UIs. Ideally what I'm thinking of would take a screenshot of the URL you enter (or create a cache, to capture all the interactive features), then store that in your collection.

Here's a site I looove the look and feel of, and the Cyrillic text just makes it prettier IMO: http://syg.ma. It'd be cool to collect inspiring UIs and see what your friends/colleagues collect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This article collects four great sources, I've used UI Patterns personally: [UX Movement 4 Best Design Pattern Libraries](http://uxmovement.com/resources/4-best-design-pattern-libraries/)

Comment: Thanks for those resources! But those are curated by others, I was looking more for a tool that lets you curate your own collection and share it with others.
Beginning to suspect that what I'm asking for hasn't been made yet so can only 1) Make it myself 2) Wait for/get someone else to make it.

Comment: See the top bar on UI Patterns, with an account you can Upload Screenshots, which seems to be what you want?

Comment: That is cool. I actually am not looking for functionality-sorted, though that is really useful. The closest thing is Behance's UI/UX category https://www.behance.net/search?field=132&content=projects but more like Pinterest where you can pin any live site's UI for others to see. (I'd feel wrong uploading other people's designs to my Behance.) I know you could blog the UIs, but there should be a platform for this.

Comment: Pinterest has plenty of threads on this, why not use it? https://www.google.com/search?q=pinterest+for+ui+elements&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8